# Listen to system reboot/shutdown event with C# - cross platform

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-6.0

If we're just talking about Windows, I can use the [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Is there something cross-platform that I can use? I want something that works with Windows and Linux. I shall be using .NET 6.0

Comment: I don't think there is any equivalent of that Windows specific class. Probably this has it roots in that there is no single session interface in *nix (each loginmanager and window manager could have it's own set of signals). The closest thing I could find was [PosixSignal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.posixsignal?view=net-6.09) which would allow you to at least detect when the system attempts to shut down your program - regardless of reason.

Comment: @fredrik The PosixSignal seems interesting, but it's just an enum. How can I listen to it? I assume there's some kind of event I can subscribe to?

Comment: Look at the other classes in the namespace. PosixSignalRegistration for exemple.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, there is no straightforward and reliable way to determine this in a Linux environment, let alone a cross-platform solution. You will need to implement a linux-specific way to detect this.

As @fredrik mentioned in the comments, using `PosixSignal` would let you know that your application is being asked to terminate, but not why. You can nevertheless examine the situation upon receiving a `SIGTERM` to determine if the system is indeed shutting down. For example, running `systemctl is-system-running` would return "stopping" if that is the case.

If we assume a modern Linux desktop environment, a more robust alternative could be to subscribe to the [D-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) signal `PrepareForShutdown`. From [the systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/):

> The PrepareForShutdown() and PrepareForSleep() signals are emitted when a system suspend or shutdown has been requested and is about to be executed, as well as after the the suspend/shutdown was completed (or failed)...

The library [Tmds.Dbus](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus) provides an async API to listen to that signal in your .net app. You will still need to deal with the fact that you'll receive this AND the `SIGTERM` in sequence.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is quite extensive and has given me a good idea what to look into. I'll keep the question open while the bounty lasts and if no one has anything better, I will award it to you.

Comment: @igg Thanks, you can also accept the answer if you think so. As more server components adopts D-Bus too, this answer still stands imo.

Comment: I think your answer is good, but since the question was originally phrased as "cross platform", I think it doesn't qualify to be the accepted answer. If there is simply no way to do this check in a cross platform way, then I'm OK with leaving this question open until then.

Comment: @igg to "is there...?" the answer is "no, there isn't", but your call, I guess.

Comment: The answer is "no there isn't, today". This question can stay open and be answered years from now.